# Interconnecting two different Knockout "apps" on the same page in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, magento2, knockoutjs

I have two blocks with a `jsLayout` in the layout XML on a single page. Both are initialized via

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php echo $block->getJsLayout(); ?>
            }
        }
</script>
```

In another Magento `.phtml` block:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#sidebar": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php echo $block->getJsLayout(); ?>
            }
        }
</script>
```

(with different BlockNames)

It is the checkout and a sidebar. The reason two have different Magento blocks is, that I want to use the sidebar also on other pages.

Now in my `.html` (not `.phtml`!) there are data-bindings:

```
 <form class="form methods-shipping" id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="submit: setShippingInformation" novalidate="novalidate">
```

`setShippingInformation` referes to the current knockout js view as I understand it. There is also the possibility to use `parent.something()`.

But Is there also a way to access the sidebar view form a checkout template and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

Views should not know about other views on page. View interconnection leads to coupled and fragile UIs.

Every view should only be responsible for rendering its bit of data, catch related user actions and pass them to actions.

All the information rendered by views should come from models, and all information set by views should go to actions. Action calls will modify models, and model state changes will trigger update on all views that are subscribed to those models. This is standard flow of inter-view communication in MVC and MVVM

Comment: So I guess I need some kind of proxy actions between those both apps? But how can I do that without duplicating to much code? My aim is to reuse as much of the existing code as possible, which is IMHO besides clear design, also a valid goal?

Comment: It does not conflict with code reuse. Your views should only have thin layer of presentation logic only used by themselves, all business logic should reside in actions and models, so you will never need to call other view, only actions and models. And since actions and models are global on page, you can access them from any view.

Comment: If you have views V1 and V2, and you need V2 to react somehow on button clicked on view V1, you should introduce model M and action A (you will probably have them anyway if you build your application using recommended MVC). V2 should be subscribed to state modifications of M (observables are easy way to do it). Button click on V1 should call A, which will modify state of M, and V2 will be automatically re-rendered with new state of M.